# Numero primo JAVA

Tags: java

Tenho que criar um algoritimo em java pra detectar os numeros primos em um intervalo que o usuario escolher por exemplo "os numeros existentes de 1 ate 50" , o resultado esta saindo correto no console do eclipse porem ele fica repetindo varias vezes a resposta (1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5) e assim por diante.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EXC29 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Entre com um numero ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 1;i<=num;i++) {
            
            boolean primo = true;
            
            for(int j = 2;j<i;j++) {
                
                if(i%j == 0) {
                    primo = false;
                }
                
                if(primo) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que seu código funcione sem imprimir números repetidos basta mover o último `if` para fora do laço mais interno. Veja também que 1 não é um número primo, logo, você deve começar o laço externo do número 2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
        System.out.println("Entre com um numero ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();       
        for(int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
            boolean primo = true;        
            for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {            
                if(i % j == 0) {
                    primo = false;
                }
            }
            if(primo) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja funcionando no Ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/h95Lox)

Dito isso, esse é um algoritmo ingênuo de tempo quadrático. Como isso tem cara de trabalho de faculdade eu recomendaria a implementação do clássico [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes), ou ainda um algoritmo mais moderno como o [Crivo de Atkin](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Atkin).